# How to have dynamic variables in config.json in next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, next.js13

I’d like to build a config.json file where I can put some variable like a title or a color hex and much more.

My web app in next js have to take the confing befor mount his component and I’d like to have a setting page for modify the variables as we want in the app.
The app should re render the components when a variable change.

How could I do this ?

I tried nothing for the moment, I don’t know what is the best. Use a config.json file with a context and some api call. Use the local storage ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a simple config file will be enough to satisfy the requirements that you have proposed above. A key value store like [Redis](https://redis.com), [Vercel KV](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-kv) or even [Vercel Edge Config](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/edge-config) to contain your settings is probably needed.

```js
import kv from '@vercel/kv';
import SettingsProvider from "@/components/SettingsProvider";

// example component with vercel kv
async function SettingsServer({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const settings = await kv.get('site-settings');
  return <SettingsProvider value={settings}>{children}</SettingsProvider>;
}
```

As you can see above, the approach I recommend is that you access the settings store via a server component and then pass it to a client context you can access everywhere on the client side within your app. Hope this helps!